# import error in python even after having init file and python path

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

I am trying to import a file in python

my directory structure is

```
maindir
    __init__.py
    constants.py

    subdirectory
          __init__.py
          code.py
```

I am trying to import constants in the code file

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ching/maindir')
from maindir import constants
```

even after that I am  getting this error

```
ImportError: No module named maindir
```

Any one got any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ching')
from maindir import constants
```