# Module not found but has init.py

Tags: python, importerror

I have the following directory structure

```
Head --
      |--Data
      |--main
            |-- header.py
            |-- __init__.py
      |--dir1
            |-- file.py
      |--dir2
      |--dir3
      |-- __init__.py
```

In `file.py` I import `class Header` defined in `header.py` using `from Head.main.header import *`.

I have all the `__init__.py`'s in place but still when I run `file.py` I get `ImportError: No module named Head.main.header`.

I am using PyCharm.

How should I solve it?

Running `tree` I got:

```
F:\PyCharmProjects\TestDir>tree
Folder PATH listing for volume MISC
Volume serial number is 0FCE-123A
F:.
├───.idea
├───Data
│   └───small
├───Head
    ├───dir1
    └───main
```

Comment: Can you use `tree` or equivalent to show us the entire structure of the project and show us the contents of `setup.py`?

Comment: There is no setup.py in the project.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey How did you resolved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can you include the import code in file.py? See this answer as well, it might have your solution: [import-error-in-python-even-after-having-init-file-and-python-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109793/import-error-in-python-even-after-having-init-file-and-python-path). Then tell us what worked!

Comment: That solution worked. But I am curious what is wrong with `__init__.py`? Everywhere it is written that `ImportError` can be solved by adding `__init__.py`??

Answer (score 0):

that is because the import is trying to locate Head in the same folder tham file.py is, first you have to include the folder of head in the path of the system so the import can locate it. To do that do this:

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
```

put all the dirname needed until get to the folder containing Head

then do yours import normally

It may look a little ugly, but the advantage is that if you later move the folder of you proyect to other place, you don't have to change the every single `sys.path.append` is you do it like this `sys.path.append("/folder1/folder2")`